# how to simplify this code? how to add a field in laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel

```php
foreach (Location::all() as $l) {
    $count = Book::where('title', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
        ->where('location_id', '=', $l->id)
        ->count();

    $dataLocation[] = array(
      'id' => $l->id,
      'code' => $l->code,
      'name' => $l->name,
      'count' => $count
    );
}

$location = collect($dataLocation);
```

how can I add a field in a laravel collection?

The value of this field is obtained from a query or logic `if else`.

[image: expected output]

I expect laravel collection can add a variable and make the code simple

Comment: What is not working? I see it is working, right?

Comment: This question _might_ be a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) (see Mast's comment). Stackoverflow is for questions on non-functioning code, while Code Review is where you go if you want to improve/optimize (if possible). But, quick answer, performing a `->count()` query inside a `foreach()` is an N+1 problem; for every record in your `locations` table, you're executing an extra query; don't do that. Define a relationship and/or use a single subquery, as illustrated below.

Comment: @TimLewis It reads like a feature request, not a request for review. I don't think this question would be salvageable for CR.

Comment: @Mast That's fair; I simply don't think it fits well on Stackoverflow either, as, again, this code is functional, but definitely not optimized. It's closed now with a solution anyway 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your expected output you should have a query like this

```
$locations = Location::withCount([ 'books' => fn($q) => $q->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%") ])
            ->select('id', 'code', 'name')
            ->get();
```

and obviously a relationship defined in your **Location** model for **Book** model like below.

```
public function books()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
}
```

Comment: In this way `where location_id = $l->id` probably not necessary, as models already binded by this field